# Found UAV, what is the purpose?

Tags: the-division

Found a UAV in game, but it looks to be too high to reach (having off edge of a building). **What is the purpose of the UAV?** It is marked on the map, but nothing is around to interact with.

Comment: They appear to be collectibles, but I've encountered that one too and have no idea how to collect it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the UAV?

Found it, when you encounter the UAV you can cross hair over it and they turn red indicating an enemy. When enough damage is done to the UAV it drops what looks like a recorder. Picking it up rewarded +300XP.

Comment: Note that when you get close to a drone, you can hear it.  It sounds like an old modem interrogation tone.  When you hear that, look up.